# Set Custom Title of the Success page in Magento

Tags: checkout, onepage-checkout

I wanted to change the title of the onepage success page.By default text is "Magento Commerce". how can i change this and set my custom title.

Please help me.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add this code in **checkout.xml**

under `checkout_onepage_success` tag

```
<reference name="head">
    <action method="setData" translate="title"><key>title</key><value>your title </value></action>
</reference>
```

Answer (score 3):

you can do it via layout files:

```
<reference name="head">
    <action method="setTitle" translate="title"><title>Your Title</title></action>
</reference>
```

or via code by accessing head block element and calling `setTitle('your title')`  method on it

```
$this->getLayout()->getBlock('head')->setTitle('your title');
```